# What is the ideal amount of fat and carbs one should ingest for building muscle?

Tags: fat, hypertrophy, carbohydrate

If one goes on the internet and searches about nutrition, usually the discussions are centered about calories and proteins. Less often, harmful fats are discussed (eg: transfats) and decreasing carbohydtes is for very special diets (keto diet). So, this led me quite unsatisfied on the amount of information on how one should control their fat and carb intake for body building.

Could some references/ resources be suggested where such topics are discussed?

Comment: @user2813274 - Please don't answer in comments. It avoids the voting system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### At least enough to not die, and extreme carbohydrate restriction is probably not great for gainz.

As long as you are getting adequate fat to support basic bodily functions, your carbohydrate and fat intakes are largely irrelevant with respect to hypertrophy. Protein is really the only important nutritional driver of hypertrophy, as long as your total energy intake is sufficient to support muscle growth, that is, you are in a calorie surplus. If you are doing concurrent training (aerobic and strength training together), you might have to watch your carbs to be sure you're getting enough to support your aerobic training, otherwise, it isn't something to be too concerned about.

For more details on optimizing your macro distribution for bulking, see the "Macronutrient Distribution While Bulking" section of this article: [Optimizing Bulking Diets To Facilitate Hypertrophy](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/bulking/). There is some evidence discussed in this section about potential downsides of extreme carbohydrate restriction. Dr. Trexler concludes that section by saying:

> As long as you’re meeting or exceeding the bare minimums for carb and fat intake, their exact ratio is pretty inconsequential while bulking, so you should feel free to eat in accordance with your preferences.

If you want to grow, eat enough protein ([at least 1.3 g/kg body weight](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/athlete-protein-intake/)), consume enough total energy to be in a modest surplus, and have a piece of toast every so often.

Comment: My understanding is that the main risk of too much protein and not enough carbs/fat was a build-up of ammonia in your system.  It's sort of in the first link but doesn't seem to be noted directly (on skimming.)